# Printing the content of web page in Java

Tags: java, html, android-developer-api, printing-web-page

I'm trying to read the content of https://example.com/ using HttpURLconnection class. I've removed the html tags between angled braces but I'm failing in removing the words between curled braces. Also there's no space between words that needs to be printed.

Here is the code:

```
    URL url = new URL("https://example.com/");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(url.openStream());
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while(sc.hasNext()) {
        sb.append(sc.next());
         }
    String result = sb.toString();

    //Removing the HTML tags
    result = result.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", " ");
    
    System.out.println("Contents of the web page: "+result);
```

And this is the output I'm getting:

Contents of the web page:     ExampleDomain     body{background-color:#f0f0f2;margin:0;padding:0;font-family:-apple-system,system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont,"SegoeUI","OpenSans","HelveticaNeue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;}div{width:600px;margin:5emauto;padding:2em;background-color:#fdfdff;border-radius:0.5em;box-shadow:2px3px7px2pxrgba(0,0,0,0.02);}a:link,a:visited{color:#38488f;text-decoration:none;}@media(max-width:700px){div{margin:0auto;width:auto;}}     ExampleDomain  Thisdomainisforuseinillustrativeexamplesindocuments.Youmayusethisdomaininliteraturewithoutpriorcoordinationoraskingforpermission.   Moreinformation...

How to remove the content between curled braces?
and how to put space between the words in sentences?

Comment: "how to put space between the words in sentences" - you can't without a dictionary. You'll need a dictionary to find out which characters make a word.

Comment: I looked at the page and there seems to be spaces between the words in the source. Why do you remove the spaces while reading the source? If you don't remove the spaces you won't need to add them back later.

Comment: Where am I removing the spaces, can you please specify that code? What will be the correct code so that this doesn't happen?

Comment: Ofcourse, `sb.append(sc.next());` should be `sb.append(" " + sc.next());` because of how `Scanner#next` works. It gives you a "word", a string without any white space. You are effectively removing the whitespace by not accomodating for the return of `next`. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--

Comment: Please mark as accepted answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the removal of content between curly braces, you can use `String#replaceAll(String, String)`. [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

```
str.replaceAll("\\{.*\\}", "");
```

This regex matches all characters between opening and closing braces. So your code would be:

```
URL url = new URL("https://example.com/");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(url.openStream());
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (sc.hasNext()) {
    sb.append(" " + sc.next());
}
String result = sb.toString();

// Removing the HTML tags
result = result.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");

// Removing the CSS stuff
result = result.replaceAll("\\{.*\\}", "");

System.out.println("Contents of the web page: " + result);
```

Comment: If you are planning to remove line breaks, this regex won't work. See https://riptutorial.com/regex/example/32238/why-doesn-t-dot-----match-the-newline-character----n---#:~:text=By%20default%20in%20most%20regex,%2C%20or%20%2Fs%20in%20PCRE.